# The centre of what we can now see in the universe

Tags: cosmology, symmetry, space-expansion, universe, galaxies

If the JWST has just discovered the furthest away galaxies in one place we can now triangulate to where the centre of what we can see
This is observable and appears not symmetric with everything expanding symetrically.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The observable universe is centered on any given observer. That is to say, from your perspective, you are the center of the universe. I can say the same for myself as well.

This is because the big bang didn't originate from any particular point in the universe, but rather resulted in the expansion of the universe wherein the distance between any two points rapidly increased. Ergo, any given observer can claim a central position.

Beyond the observable universe? We can't say. Essentially by definition, we know nothing about it, but it stands to good reason that it shouldn't differ in this regard.